# Unable to transfer my BTC funds from app wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

How can I remove my Bitcoin from an app-based wallet? It's a non-custodial wallet and generally gets good reviews. I've tried to transfer the BTC from the app to my hardware wallet three times now, but the transactions don't go through. The latest transaction has been "frozen" since yesterday. When I enter the transaction hash in blockchain info sites I get the response "No transaction found".

I've been in touch with their customer services, and the agent told me their developers are working on the problem, but I've had no more contact with them for more than 20 hours. Is there any other way to transfer the BTC, or any way to take further action?

Comment: Which app are you talking about?

Comment: Enjin. I have heard back from their customer services now and they suggest I import the Enjin wallet into a new wallet. Trying this now.

Comment: Just making sure, this is customer support you specifically reached out to through their website, not a "representative" that contacted you after posting this problem on another forum, right? The latter is a common scam vector.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely customer support. I contacted them directly through the app. I have removed all my crypto from that app now.

Answer (score 1):

> It's a non-custodial wallet [...] Is there any other way to transfer the BTC?

If it is genuinely a non-custodial wallet you should be able to transfer into a different wallet program either the keys, the master seed, the master key or the recovery phrase (also known as seed phrase or backup phrase)

Things to be aware of

- If recovering from a recovery phrase, both wallets must use the same dictionary and algorithms. The most common one is BIP-39. More wallets support that than anything else. Electrum has its own system but can use BIP-39 if specified. Bitcoin-core doesn't use recovery phrases at all.
- Both wallets must support the same derivation path.
- If Enjin's Bitcoin wallet is a hierarchical deterministic (HD) wallet, as most are, you need to be sure the new wallet is also and supports the same definition such as BIP-32.
- If you import individual keys, you need to make special wallet backup arrangements since imported keys are not recoverable from recovery phrases alone.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful information. I've been struggling with this all afternoon, and I seem to have finally got the wallet imported into a different wallet now. I've sent a small amount from the new wallet as a test, and I'm just waiting for confirmation, but it seemed to go through smoothly. I was very confused by the BIP-39 thing, so that's a very clear explanation.